# ¿Hay alguna forma de adaptar el texto al tamaño de un div de forma responsiva?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hay alguna manera de hacer que el texto que esta dentro de un div ocupe el 100% de este y se vaya ajustando si el div cambia su tamaño?
O solo queda usar @media ?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

Que tal para esto podrias utilizar `vw` unidad. Es significado de "Viewport Width" utilizando esto el texto sera del tamaño del navegador. Puedes testear utilizando este codigo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>

<h1 style="font-size:10vw;">Texto Responsivo</h1>

<p style="font-size:5vw;">Cambia de tamaño la pantalla para ver el cambio de escala de tamaños.</p>

<p style="font-size:5vw;">Utiliza "vw" cuando cambies de tamaño el texto. 10vw configurara el tamaño a un 10% del "Viewport Width".</p>

<p>Viewport es el tamaño del navegador. 1vw = 1% del viewport width. Si el viewport es 50cm wide, 1vw es 0.5cm.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar a hacer lo siguiente

```css
div#contenedor-texto {
width=80%;
}

p {
width=100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Texto 100%</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor-texto">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En CSS no se usa el símbolo de igual (=) para indicar el valor de la propiedad, sino los  dos puntos  (:).